# Get sum with php

Tags: php

I have following codes

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Javascript function </title>

    <style type="text/css">
    .box
    {
        width:400px;
        background-color:#F0F8FF;
    }

    h4
    {
        color:#09F
    }

    </style>

<script type="text/javascript">
function hello(){
var xx=eval(form1.text1.value);
var yy=eval(form1.text2.value);
form1.text3.value=xx+yy
}
</script>

  </head>
    <body onLoad="form1.text1.focus()">  
    <center>
    <div class="box">
    <h1 style="color:#2c80d3 ">Javascript Function</h1>
    <table border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="1" width="25%"> 
        <form name="form1" action="textboxes.php" method="Post">
    <tr><td> First</d><td width="20px"><input type="text" name="text1"  value=""></td></tr>
      <tr><td> Second</d><td><input type="text" name="text2"  value="" onBlur="hello()"></td></tr>
     <tr><td> Result</d><td><input type="text" name="text3"  value="" disabled=""></td></tr>
    </form>
    </table>
    <h4>Enter any digit in text1 and text2 and see result in text3</h4>

        <h4>Is it possible to do above with php without submitting FORM?</h4>

    </div>
    </center>
    </body>
</html>
```

No problem, It works fine.
I used java script to sum two numbers.
Is it possible to add two numbers with php without using any submit button?

If yes then please guide me.

http://i41.tinypic.com/2rfev7m.jpg

Comment: What is it you think `var xx=eval(form1.text1.value);` is doing? If you're just trying to convert to a number, that's about the worst possible way to do it. Try `parseInt` or `parseFloat` instead.

Comment: You can do that with PHP but with providing a submit button, without that you cant, instead try doing it using jquery or javascript.

Comment: You could use a combination of jQuery and AJAX to send the numbers and get the result on every change of one of the inputs. Why would you want to do this, though, since JavaScript is fairly capable of adding numbers?

Comment: Feels like time-travelled 10 years - a center tag!!!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it without a submit button and in php, you can use an AJAX request in javascript to the server, which will compute to value and then return it to the client.

Answer (score 0):

here is the working sample.

First of all we need to create a html file named add.html.
here is the code of the add.html file…

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
 <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
 <head>
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
 <title>Addition</title>
 </head>
 <body>
 <form action="result.php" method="post">
 Enter first Integer: <input type="text" name="first" size="5" /><br/>
 Enter second Integer: <input type="text" name="sec" size="5" /><br/>
 <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Add" />
 </form>

 </body>
 </html>
```

place it in the pseudo server folder. If your pseudo server is WampServer, then the path of the file will be

C:/wamp/www/add.html

now open your favorite browser and to the address bar type

localhost/add.html

You can see the add.html page. add with number

You can see two text box where you can input the numbers and a submit button. You can input two numbers into the input boxes and press the submit button (The Add button). But nothing will happen. Because the php will do the adding job.

Lets create the php file. You can name it result.php. As I have already declared in the add.html form action is the result.php.

```
<form action="result.php" method="post">
```

if you give different name of the php file then please change the form action php name in add.html.
Here is the php code of result.php…

```
<?php //Starting of php
 $first = $_POST['first']; //Getting Value of first integer from add.html
 $sec = $_POST['sec']; //Getting Value of Second integer from add.html
 $res = $first + $sec; //Adding the two values and placing the added result to 'res' variable
 echo 'Added Result:';
 echo $first." + ".$sec." = ".$res; //Showing the result to the screen
 //Ending of php
 ?>
```

save this result.php file in the server path where you have already placed the add.html file.
Now it is the time to test. Open your favorite browser and in the address bar type…

localhost/add.html

enter two numbers and hit the Add button. you will see that the browser will direct you to the result.php page where you can see the added result.

hope this will help you.